# C# - Snare Drum Sound Detection from an imported MP3 or WAV file. Possible?

Tags: c#, algorithm, audio, detection, waveform

Im having troubles about this problem. A program that detects a snare drum sound from a sound file, generates it's wave form, and emphasize the part where the snare drum was detected. Does this program, perhaps exist? :) This is the research/thesis assigned to me. I've been researching about possible algorithms and i've seen some of initial research. This is included in the field of sound detection right? Can you please tell me some ideas or any material, code snippets that I can use? I really appreciate it. Thank You! :)

Comment: Do we get awarded your degree/masters/doctorate if we help you with this? ;-) Just kidding. spender's answer looks good.

Answer (score 5):

Percussion sounds have different characteristics. Kick drum has most energy in the lower part of the frequency spectrum and cymbals/hats have most energy in the high end of the frequency spectrum. Snare drum distribution is generally fairly wide and similar in timbre to wideband noise. So to detect this, you'd have to perform a fourier transform over the signal to perform analysis in the frequency domain rather than the time domain, and detect percussive wideband noise. You'd definitely be better off asking this on a DSP forum rather than a programmer's forum.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that helps you, but [HERE](http://www.un4seen.com/) you can get a .net Library (free for non-commercial) which can do such stuff. May you can use ILSpy to take a look at their algorithems...